# Internal wiki setup to create a book or export-to-PDF feature

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wikipedia

Is there any tutorial to setup an internal intranet wiki to enable creation of a book or export-to-PDF as in `wikipedia.org`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to setup [MediaWiki first](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/mediawiki/mediawiki_installation.htm) and then install the [PDF Book export extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPdf_Book).